# The email could not be sent. Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function

Tags: wordpress

I have installed WordPress. I created a MultiWebsite, so I could access two websites. I logged in and it worked.

When I needed to login again, it's asking me for username and password. Since the password was generated by WordPress itself, I do not know it.

It's showing me the following:

> The email could not be sent. Possible reason: your host may have
>   disabled the mail() function.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Where are you hosting the website?

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers block the SMTP services to prevent the server from being blacklisted and some provide the authenticated emails sending only. You can use any of the following transactional email services and configure it with Postman SMTP (https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/)

- Mailgun https://www.mailgun.com/
- Sendinblue https://www.sendinblue.com/

Alternatively, you can also configure your Google mail account to send the emails with the same plugin.